# How to set max size for splitter panel PrimeNg?

Tags: angular, primeng

I use this [splitter](https://primeng.org/splitter). It has `minSize` props to fix minimum size. How is about max size?

I have tried to check it using events `onResizeStart()`, `onReisizeStop()`, but it has no data about current width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event `onResizeEnd` which gives you an array of the new sizes.

[image: Event description]

You can find a demo of how to use the two events to prevent the user from going over the size limit [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitter-demo-m1er4c?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: I need to limit max size. For examle user can not resize splitter more then 200px;

Comment: See the StackBlitz demo.